# $\mathsf{Top}$ with proper maps has products.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

In I.M. James' *General Topology and Homotopy Theory*, he presents proper maps before introducing compact sets, by defining $\phi:X \to Y$ to be proper iff $\phi \times \text{Id}_T$ is closed for all $T \in \mathsf{Top}$. He then mentions that it is clear that the product of proper maps is proper by theorems we already have. How can I go about showing this without even using the notion of a compact set?

I have $\phi_i: X_i \to Y_i$ such that $\phi_i \times \text{Id}_T$ is closed for all $T \in \mathsf{Top}$. I want to show that $\prod_i \phi_i \times \text{Id}_T$ is closed for all $T \in \mathsf{Top}$.

The theorems we have so far about products of maps are not many: we know that given $\phi: X \to Y$, the graph function $\Gamma_\phi: X \to X \times Y$ is an embedding. We know that a product of open maps is open, and a product of (closed) embeddings is a (closed) embedding. We know stuff about pullbacks, pushouts, and joins.

Any ideas for this? By comparison, showing that the coproduct of proper maps is proper is pretty easy because $\left( \coprod_i \phi_i \right) \times \text{Id}_T = \coprod_i \left( \phi_i \times \text{Id}_T \right)$, and the coproduct of closed maps is closed.

Comment: Does he mean an arbitrary product, or a finite one?

Comment: Surely it must be finite. The infinite version implies Tychonoff's theorem.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Actually it's not clear. (I like this text, but there are some typos and ambiguities.) He says "the category of spaces and [proper] maps admits both coproduct and product..."

Comment: That's obviously false: the category of spaces + proper maps has no terminal object.

Comment: @ZhenLin What's wrong with it having no terminal object? How does that contradict anything the author says?

Comment: Some people call these maps *proper*, others call them *perfect*, while reserving *proper* for maps such that the preimage of a compact set is compact. One can show that every perfect map is proper. That means if all maps are perfect and the category has non-compact spaces, then the terminal object cannot be compact. One the other hand, a non-compact space would not be terminal.

Comment: @EricAuld A category with finite products in particular has an empty product, i.e. a terminal object.

Comment: Note that if $f:X\to Y$ is proper, then $f\times\mathbf 1_Z$ is not only closed, but again proper. Also, the composition of proper maps is proper. Now if $f_1:X_1\to Y_1$ and $f_2:X_2\to Y_2$ are proper, then $f_1\times\mathbf 1_{X_2}$ and $\mathbf 1_{Y_1}\times f_2$ are proper, thus their composition $f_1\times f_2$ is proper as well. For general finite products, the claim follows by induction.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thanks! So perhaps the statement should be that finite, but not empty, products exist in this category?

Comment: No, the correct statement is that the class of proper maps is closed under finite products in $\mathbf{Top}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin So I suppose this implies that all finite products of objects exist, except the empty product?

Comment: No. The point is that products in the category of spaces + continuous maps are not necessarily products in the category of spaces + proper maps.